# Slow Video with an ATI x1300

Tags: video, ati, youtube

ive got an ati x1300 with its drives installed, but when I see videos un youtube (sd or hd) they see slow, and chopped.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The only driver available for this graphic chipset is the `radeon` package from the official repository, do not install any fglrx version, it simply do not support your card.

In previous release there was some problems with the X1x00 series using the radeon driver, apparently this issues are still there and honestly i do not think that there is too much hurry to solve this, it's a really old videocard only supported by open and limited driver.

To give you an idea you can find topics on the internet about issues with the X1x00 series from 3-4 years ago to now.

Unset the "hardware video acceleration" for flash and try this way, also you can try the HTML5 version for some website like youtube or vimeo.

In the end, considering the software and the performance of your video card this is a normal behaviour.